# Deny a user to access Iframe web page using asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iframe

In my default web page i have some pop-up Iframe when a user click something (using JS).

How can i prevent users from go directly to the link : `WWW.mydomain.com/Iframe.aspx`
and see the full page but still give them the access whenever they click the Iframe button from the default page.

default - default.aspx
Iframe - Iframe.aspx.

Thanks.

Comment: in your main page (the one containing the iframe), you could generate a use-once token that the iframe accepts as an GET argument and won't display unless it receives a valid token (ie. if visited through direct URL with an old or no token by a user).

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique called [Frame killer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller) used by web applications to prevent their web pages from being displayed within a frame. In your case, it's a bit opposite, but we can borrow a similar idea.

If you display your `Iframe.aspx` as a popup when you click a button. You could check for the `window.opener` in your `Iframe.aspx` throw error if `window.opener` is empty. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(!window.opener) {
      throw new Error();       
  }
</script>
```

If your `Iframe.aspx` is embedded in an iframe of the popup. You could check it further using `window.parent.opener`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      if(!window.parent.opener) {
          throw new Error();       
      }
    </script>
```

Note that this technique does have limitations as pointed out in the link above.